# Negative number in formula Python

Tags: python

So I'm writing a loan calculator program for my Computer Science class and I'm stuck. In the formula for calculating the total payment amount, it has a negative number. I can't figure out how to fix it. I still have to add a while loop so the program isn't finished just. But here's my program so far:

```
import math
# Returns the number of payments per year
def get_payments_per_year(frequency):
    if frequency == "a":
        return 1
    elif frequency == "s":
        return 2
    elif frequency == "q":
        return 4
    elif frequency == "m":
        return 12
    elif frequency == "d":
        return 365

# Loan calculation functions removed; don't get called after the error.

# main
another = "Y"
amount = int(input("Enter amount of loan: "))
annual_ir = int(input("Enter annual interest rate: "))
payoff_yrs = int(input("Enter payoff period in years: "))

print("How frequently will you pay?")
frequency = input("[a]nnually \ [s]emi-annually \ [q]uarterly \ [m]onthly \ [d]aily? ")
payment_count = get_payments_per_year(frequency)

dec_annual_ir = annual_ir / 100
per_int_rate = dec_annual_ir / payment_count
total_pay_count = frequency * payoff_yrs
total_pay = (per_int_rate * amount) / (1 - (math.pow((1 + per_int_rate),-total_pay_count)))
# Code after this point isn't executed.
```

It comes back with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 81, in <module>
    total_pay = (per_int_rate * amount) / (1 - (math.pow((1 + per_int_rate),-total_pay_count)))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have an illegal operation in `-total_pay_count`.  Look at the data flow:

```
payoff_yrs = int(input("Enter payoff period in years: "))
frequency = input("[a]nnually \ [s]emi-annually \ [q]uarterly \ [m]onthly \ [d]aily? ")
total_pay_count = frequency * payoff_yrs
```

`total_pay_count` is a string.  For my 30-year monthly loan, it's a string of 30 'm's.  I think you want

```
payment_count = get_payments_per_year(frequency)
total_pay_count = payment_count * payoff_yrs
```